# How do I mute react-query console errors when a promise rejects?

Tags: jestjs, react-query

I'm testing a custom hook powered by `react-query`. I needed to test its rollback behavior when a promise rejects. Unfortunately, `react-query` logs rejected promises to the console using `console.error`, which dirties up my test output. How can I prevent `react-query` from logging rejected promises as console errors?

Answer (score 13):

`react-query` has a method called [`setLogger`](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/setLogger#_top) ([used to be called `setConsole`](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/migrating-to-react-query-3#setconsole-has-been-replaced-by-the-new-setlogger-function)) that you can use to achieve this.

To mute all console messages from `react-query`:

```js
setLogger({
    log: () => {},
    warn: () => {},
    error: () => {},
});
```

To again unmute `react-query`:

```js
setLogger(window.console);
```

If you wish to only mute some levels and not others, you can, by setting any combination of empty functions and `window.console` functions. For example:

```js
setLogger({
    log: () => {},
    warn: window.console.warn,
    error: window.console.error,
});
```

If you only want to mute the logger for a single test, these calls can be made at the beginning and end of the test in question.

If you'd rather mute the logger for an entire test file, you can use Jest's [setup and teardown methods](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown):

```js
beforeAll(() => {
  setLogger({
    log: () => {},
    warn: () => {},
    error: () => {},
  });
});

afterAll(() => {
  setLogger(window.console);
});
```

If you wish to mute the logger for all tests in your suite, you can add the call to a test setup file (named, for example, `testSetup.js`), and then add the following to your jest configuration:

```js
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/testSetup.js'],
```

I personally created a helper function to use in my tests (TypeScript):

```js
export async function withMutedReactQueryLogger(
  func: () => Promise<any>
): Promise<any> {
  const noop = () => {
    // do nothing
  };

  setLogger({
    log: noop,
    warn: noop,
    error: noop,
  });

  const result = await func();

  setLogger(window.console);

  return result;
}
```

I use it like this:

```js
test('test something', async () => {
  await withMutedReactQueryLogger(async () => {
    // write my test here
  })
})
```

Comment: this is no longer actual, please update the answer https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/testing#turn-off-network-error-logging

Comment: If using MSW, is there any reason why I **wouldn't** want to add this at a global level during tests?

Answer (score 4):

As [Nathan Arthur answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65570463/10265935),

React Query version 4 (TanStack Query v4). `setLogger` function is **removed**. [Read more](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/migrating-to-react-query-4#setlogger-is-removed).

It will config inside `QueryClient` option instead.

```js
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  logger: {
    log: (...args) => {
      // Log debugging information
    },
    warn: (...args) => {
      // Log warning
    },
    error: (...args) => {
      // Log error
    },
  },
})
```

Ref:

- https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/testing#turn-off-network-error-logging
- https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/custom-logger